# Filter the query ONLY for the search results page

Tags: functions, filters, query, search, page-template

I am trying to customize the search results for a generic search, but **only** if it's using the `search.php` template. I have other searches on my site, and I don't want this filter interfering with them. Everything works on the following code, except for `is_page_template('search.php')`.

Once I enter that line of code as a condition, it just reverts to the normal search filtering, because my IF condition is failing. How do I only run my code if we're on the `search.php` page?

```
    //Filter the search for only posts and parts
    function SearchFilter($query)
    {
        if ($query->is_search && is_page_template('search')) {
            $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'parts'));
            $query->set('meta_key', 'Manufacturer');
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
            $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        }
        return $query;
    }

    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'SearchFilter');
```

Comment: I suppose `is_page_template` runs _after_ `pre_get_posts`. That's why you can't use it yet.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Is there another way to check? I'm going to experiment with WP_Query inside the template itself, but it feels kind of silly to have WordPres check the normal way, and then tell it to change its mind and try another way...

Answer (score 6):

Lets break it down step by step:

`if ($query->is_search && is_page_template('search')) {`

There are 3 problems here

### `is_page_template`

`search.php` isn't a page template, that's not how the search template is loaded. So this won't work.

But if it did work, there's a new problem. Functions such as `is_page_template` etc rely on the main query, but we're in a `pre_get_posts` filter, you don't know if that query has been set yet, or if you're filtering that query or another.

So we need to:

- remove the  `is_page_template` check, it doesn't do what you think it does
- Add an `$query->is_main_query()` check so the filter doesn't interfere with widgets and other queries

### Methods vs member variables

`if ($query->is_search`

This doesn't work, and should be generating PHP warnings for you. The problem is that `is_search` is a function/method not a variable, it should be:

`if ( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {`

### But `search.php`?

WordPress decides which template is loaded based on the main query. If it's the main query, and `is_search` is true, then `search.php` will be loaded.

Because of this, WordPress hasn't decided which template to use when your filter happens. In fact, you can make WordPress change which template it loads by modifying the query variables. For example, if you unset all the variables, and tell it to load a single post, you won't get `search.php`, or an archive at all, you're likely to get `single.php` instead

### What About Search Queries in Page Templates?

`is_main_query` will be false, so not an issue

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround that might cost you an extra query. However, @Milo once mentioned that WordPress is pretty smart about caching the queries, so this shouldn't be a big deal for you.

You can run the query inside the `pre_get_posts` and then do some checks. If the situation matched your requirements, then filter the query:

```
//Filter the search for only posts and parts
function SearchFilter($query)
{
    remove_action('pre_get_posts', 'SearchFilter');
    // Run the query to fetch the results
    $posts = get_posts( $query->query );
    if(!empty($posts)) {
        // Check the template for the first post 
        if( get_page_template_slug( $posts[0]->ID ) == 'YOUR SLUG HERE' ){
            $search_template = true; 
        } else {
            $search_template = false; 
        }
    }
    // Now filter the posts
    if ($query->is_main_query() & $query->is_search && $search_template) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'parts'));
        $query->set('meta_key', 'Manufacturer');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
    return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'SearchFilter');
```